# XmlReader.Read() getting name and value

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I've been at this for a few hours now and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. 
my psuedo xml file:

```
<Parent>
    <child Seq="1">
        <Num1>1137555</Num1>
    </Child>
    <Child2>
        <Text1>random text</Text1>
    </Child2>
</Parent>
```

I'm trying to get a reference to the Elements Name(in this case "Num1") and it's value("1137555"). I understand that the reader will read Num1 first, and then the content but my code seems to be skipping over a large chunk of my xml. I have about 16 different child elements nested in the parent element but i'm only getting back perhaps the last half of them.
My Code:

```
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Name);
    }
    if (xmlReader.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the type of the element is not what you think. I am betting there is another type you are missing in your if statement. Debug through the nodes and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would suggest to take a look at [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

2) There is an error in your XML structure your first Child node is invalid.

`<child></Child>`  (the first **c** is not in capital case)

Here is my code using XDocument:

```
var xml = "<Parent><Child Seq='1'><Num1>1137555</Num1></Child><Child2><Text1>random text</Text1></Child2></Parent>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var child in document.Root.Elements("Child"))
{
    child.Element("Num1").Value.Dump();
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of XmlReader and Xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "Parent")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("Parent");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement parent = (XElement)XDocument.ReadFrom(reader);
                    foreach (XElement child in parent.Elements())
                    {
                        XElement grandchild = child.Elements().FirstOrDefault();
                        Console.WriteLine("tag : '{0}', value : '{1}'", grandchild.Name.LocalName, (string)grandchild);
                    }

                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```